# Use MFC CObject serialization concept or use my own?

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

I am developing serialization concept for data structure compiled from more classes and I still thinking, if use `CObject::serialize` concept, with `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` or if I should make my own serialization functions, with `CArchive`, but without `CObject`.
What is reason to inheriting my class from `CObject` and use `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL`?
I use MFC library.

Comment: Since serialization isn't part of the Standard C++ language, what library are you talking about?

Comment: I had in my mind MFC Library.

Comment: You might add the MFC tag and edit the question title.  Opinion: I don't trust CArchive / CObject to serialize / deserialize documents correctly in the face of object changes.  Add a field or new object(s), and suddenly a file from a year ago is unreadable.  It's better to have document formats like PNG and XML that are not tied to the current code or language.  Include a version in the document format.

Comment: Are you planning on hooking it with an MDI MFC application, with Document/View architecture?  Or are you wanting vanilla serialization?  There are some benefits for the former and utilizing CObject serialization (it handles multiple versions/schemas of your document BTW).  But if you don't need it for that - don't bother.  Another question - is this serialized data planned to be utilized across different hardware platforms, e.g. streamed over the Internet, so little endian, big endian concerns?

Comment: @DaveS XML doesn't magically solve the issue of versioning. And unlike XML, `CArchive` has [versioning support`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carchive-class#getobjectschema) built in. You are distrusting the wrong serialization format here.